# How can we assert the boolean data type in postman tests

Tags: javascript, api, postman

I want to assert the boolean data type in the postman. The data value could have true or false. How should we achieve this? I m using this code to verify but it will pass only if it's true but I want to validate if the value is false as well.

```
pm.test("Verify the past event dvr details", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
 pm.expect(jsonData.data.entries[0].live_stream_rule.target_stream.dvr.is_available).to.be.true;
});
```

Comment: You would need to add https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-asserttype/ to be able to check if it's a boolean. What other values could it be? Are you trying to make sure that it exists?

Answer (score 3):

```js
pm.test("Verify the past event dvr details", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
 pm.expect(jsonData.data.entries[0].live_stream_rule.target_stream.dvr.is_available).to.be.a("boolean");
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This is correct and should be accepted as the direct answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

[PLEASE NOTE: This answer is incorrect and contains invalid code- see answer by Stanislav Scurtu]

If this what you're thinking of?

```
const isAvailable = jsonData.data.entries[0].live_stream_rule.target_stream.dvr.is_available
pm.expect(typeof isAvailable).to.be('boolean')
```

Comment: TypeError: pm.expect(...).to.be is not a function.    Getting this error after using the above

Comment: gotcha, I was just using the syntax above assuming it was correct